# Efficiently split one SQLite database into multiple files

Tags: sqlite

Is there an efficient way to split on sqlite Database into multiple files by one of their columns? So for example, if I start with one database which has:

```
full.db:
  event_id|type
  --------+----
  8896631 | a
  8896632 | b
  8896633 | c
  8896634 | b
  8896635 | a
  8896636 | a
```

I want to end up with 3 new DB files:

```
a.db:
  event_id|type
  --------+----
  8896631 | a
  8896635 | a
  8896636 | a

b.db:
  event_id|type
  --------+----
  8896632 | b
  8896634 | b

c.db:
  event_id|type
  --------+----
  8896633 | c
```

A little more backstory: I have a 1TB sqlite3 file stored on a cluster's network filesystem and each of some 40,000 different tasks across about 1000 nodes are trying to access it. This is not scaling well, so I'm wondering if I can do a pre-processing step to break this giant sqlite file into smaller pieces so that each task only needs access to one of these pieces.

Comment: With that kind of usage pattern, you want a client/server database, not sqlite.

Comment: you want to split on `type`value how many distinct value you have ?

Comment: 100,000s of values for type. sharding would also be fine (1000 DBs each with 100 or so types).